# Doctrine: ORM QueryBuilder or DBAL QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, query-builder, dbal

DBAL Query Builder:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.3/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Query.QueryBuilder.html

ORM Query Builder:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html

Inside Doctrine there is 2 QueryBuilder that are quite similar, the DBAL one and the ORM one.

What is the difference between those 2? Is there a big overhead using the ORM queryBuilder compared to the DBAL one ?

(native query are out of question as I need to use dynamic where statement)

Answer (score 10):

If you use **ORM** go with ORM one. Otherwise you should just use **DBAL**. Below you can find some details about what they actually do.

**DBAL** stands for **Database Abstraction Layer**. It tries to abstract as much of the database specific stuff like drivers or query syntax, so they can be interchangeable without the need for altering your code.

**ORM** stands for **Object Relational Mapping** this goes even further than DBAL, and attempts to bind the database schema to actual classes within your application.

Both of these come with a query builder. DBAL query builder is more basic, as it only provides a compatibility with several drivers/databases. You still operate on tables, and you still get rows as results. ORM query builder, on the other hand, is designed to work with entities (classes to which the database schema is bound).

For example, a DBAL query:

```
$builder->select('u.id, e.id, e.email')
    ->from('users', 'u')
    ->leftJoin('u', 'emails', 'e', 'u.id = e.user_id')
    ->where('u.id = :id')
    ->setParameter(':id', $id);

$rows = $builder->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Here, we create a query which joins the `users` table with the `emails` table, to get all email addresses of the user with id `$id`. The result will be in the form of an associative array. Now let's take a look at ORM:

```
$builder->select('u','e')
    ->leftJoin('u.emails', 'e')
    ->where('u.id = :id')
    ->setParameter(':id', $id);

$user = $builder->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Here, we say we want to get the `User` with id `$id` with all of his `Email` email addresses. We don't care what table they come from or what the relations between them are. What you get is an instance of `User` class with a collection of `Email` objects. All populated with the right data thanks to ORM mapping.

Comment: Would also like to note that the ORM also supports [native SQL queries](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/native-sql.html) and custom result-set mapping. For reporting purposes, aggregate data and similar, you should avoid the use of ORM Entities in favor of using table queries, to reduce the inherent overhead from the business logic that Entities provide when instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

The first is for SQL queries, the second is for DQL ones.

Most often, get the QueryBuilder instance from the `EntityManager::createQueryBuilder()` (maybe through a Repository class, see `EntityRepository;;createQueryBuilder()`), in this case you'll use the `Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder` and so write DQLs.

If you need to run SQL queries, you'll use the `Doctrine\DBAL\QueryBuilder`, instance often retrieved from `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::createQueryBuilder()` through `EntityManager::getConnection()`.

You can read more about [the benefits of use DQL over SQL in doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530409/with-doctrine-what-are-the-benefits-of-using-dql-over-sql) (and inverse).